# SQL Boolean property and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a column in my SQL table, that I wanted to make a boolean property, but there wasn't one so I made it an int and used 1 for yes and 0 for no.  Is there a way that I can add a dropdown list to a listview in visual studio containing the values Yes and No?

Essentially so I can Bind the column to the dropdown, rather than when updating the record the user can select Yes or No rather than enter 1 or 0?

Comment: a `bit` might have worked better for what you want, a value which can be either 1 or 0. In .NET it translates to true or false values. To answer the rest of the question requires a few more details. How are you getting the value from SQL and into the asp.net site?

Comment: Using bit or bool would be preferable depending on what version of SQL you have. There should be something along those lines that you can use

Comment: 1+ @ drachenstern for being the fastest keyboard in the west lol

Comment: @Terrance ~ Thanks, haha. I have a tendency of answering in the comments instead of answers, so I put one in both places, still managed to be in the top few answerers ;)

Comment: ~ Welcome to StackOverflow, glad to have you aboard. Seeing as how you appear to be new here, is there anything we can help you with? You seem to ask a lot of questions but not mark many answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a column type called "bit" which is exactly for this purpose.

Second, I would bind to a list of user friendly names for the drop down. Or, you could use a checkbox?  All you need to do is translate that to a bool and pass it to sql.

Answer (score 3):

> Essentially so I can Bind the column to the dropdown, rather than when updating the record the user can select Yes or No rather than enter 1 or 0?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"> 
  <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: This Answer is the same as mine but more clearer , thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an enumeration:

```
enum BooleanValue
{
    No = 0,
    Yes = 1
}
```

And then to use it:

```
BooleanValue myBool = (BooleanValue)myIntegerValue;
myBool.ToString(); // returns "No"
```

For reference, the `bit` SQL datatype corresponds to `bool` in .Net.

Comment: @drachenstern: Agreed; I would have gone with the `bit` sql type. However, this method leaves room for a third (or even a fourth...) boolean value to be added later :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make the Text of the Item List as Yes & the Item Value 1
same goes for the second text of the Item List as No & the Item Value 0

then use the SeletedValue Property

Comment: +1 for pointing out to use the `SelectedValue` property in the codebehind.

Comment: thanks man , i need to work on this code editing thing :) , my answers are messy